# Get widget position in a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

How to get the widget position when it is in a CustomScrollView > SliverToBoxAdapter. My widget ZoomItem zoom by creating a new widget with overlay, but when I scroll up or down, or when I change the size of the window the overlay appear aside. Why "final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);" still return the same position? Is there a way to update the renderBox? Why there is no update of the offset in my code?

ZoomItem:

```
class ZoomItem extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ZoomItem({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ZoomItemState createState() => _ZoomItemState();
}

class _ZoomItemState extends ConsumerState<ZoomItem>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;

  late bool hasReachedTop;
  late double height, width, xPosition, yPosition;

  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> animTween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    hasReachedTop = true;
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400));

    _animationController.addListener(() {
      if (_animationController.isDismissed) {
        closeDropDown();
      }
    });
    animTween = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 2.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut));


    final scrollController = ref.read(scrollControllerProvider);
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
        if (scrollController.position.pixels == 0) {
          hasReachedTop = true;
        } else {
          hasReachedTop = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (onEnter) {
          insertOverlay(context);
        },
        onExit: (onExit) {
          if (!_animationController.isAnimating) {
            closeDropDown();
          }
        },
        child: widget.child);
  }

  void insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    closeDropDown();
    findDropdownData(context);
    overlayEntry = _createOverlay();
    Overlay.of(context)!.insert(overlayEntry!);
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlay() {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Positioned(
              top: yPosition,
              left: xPosition,
              height: height,
              width: width,
              child: MouseRegion(
                  onEnter: (onEnter) {
                    _animationController.forward();
                  },
                  onExit: (onExit) {
                    _animationController.reverse();
                  },
                  child:
                      ScaleTransition(scale: animTween, child: widget.child))),
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  void findDropdownData(BuildContext context) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;


    height = renderBox.size.height;
    width = renderBox.size.width;
    final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    xPosition = offset.dx - kPaddingHorizontal;
    final top = hasReachedTop ? kSliverTop : 0;
    yPosition = offset.dy - top;
  }

  void closeDropDown() {
    if (overlayEntry != null) {
      overlayEntry!.remove();
      overlayEntry = null;
    }
  }
}
```

GridViewStaggered:

```
class GridViewStaggered extends StatelessWidget {
  final ResponsiveLayoutSize currentSize;
  final List<Item> listItem;
  const GridViewStaggered({Key? key, required this.currentSize, required this.listItem}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StaggeredGrid.count(

        children: [

          for(int i = 0 ; i < listItem.length; i++)
            StaggeredGridTile.count(
              crossAxisCellCount: i % 2 == 0 ? 2:1,
              mainAxisCellCount: i % 2 == 0 ? 2:1,
              child: i.isEven? ItemCard(
                item: listItem[i],
              ):ZoomItem(
                child: ItemCard(
                  item: listItem[i],
                ),
              ),
            )
        ],
        crossAxisCount: 4);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey there, did you find the solution to this, unfortunately, I'm facing the same issue, the issue is render box position is not being updated when scaling, I'm using a responsive framework package to make the UI responsive for mobile, tablet, and desktop,

Comment: Unfortunately not at all.